# Component flashing issues with css background image in NextJS

Tags: css, next.js, background, jsx, background-image

So I have a banner on several pages of my nextjs project with background images. On specific renders, there is a flash moment on specific renders of the page that occur before the background image is fully rendered in. These "specific renders" include when I navigate to those pages for the first time.

```
      <div className={styles.bannerImageContainer}>
     // rest of the content
```

that is the parent div of the banner component with style:

```
.bannerImageContainer {
  display: flex;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.35),
      rgba(32, 31, 31, 0.35)
    ),
    url(../../../public/assets/banners/home-banner.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Is there anything that I'm doing resulting in this flash.

I've researched flash of unstyled content (FOUC) and tried a few proposed solutions where I used inline css with `style={{...}}`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem in this case.